# Acer ASPIRE 4745, ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, acer

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Acer Aspire 4745 laptop. After installing Ubuntu I can not scroll using touch pad. How could I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening a terminal and typing:

```
synclient VertEdgeScroll=1
synclient HorizEdgeScroll=1
```

and see if that helps...

To make this change permanent, go to a terminal and type: `gksudo gedit`, type on the first line: `#!/bin/sh` and on the second and third line, copy-paste the above lines.

Save the file under `/usr/local/bin/MakeScrollWork.sh` and type in a terminal:

```
sudo chmod a+xr /usr/local/bin/MakeScrollWork.sh
```

Then type in the dash `Startup Applications`, click <kbd>Add</kbd> and type in the "Command" field: `/usr/local/bin/MakeScrollWork.sh`.   In "Name" and "Comment" you can put anything you want that will make you remember in the future what this was all about...  ;)

Click a final <kbd>Add</kbd> to put it into the list and verify that the check box is selected.

Log out and log in to test.

Comment: Fabby, is your answer completely up to date with all these comments? Comments are not meant for extended discussions and should not hold vital information the answer is lacking. Thanks!

Comment: @Seth total newbie who doesn't know a terminal from a GUI...  Or at least: *did*!  ;)  The answer was and still is valid.  He just made some mistakes that needed rectifying. :(

Comment: Well I'm going to move these comments [to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19033/discussion-on-answer-by-fabby-acer-aspire-4745-ubuntu-14-04-lts-32-bit) to keep the comments here cleaner. Thanks for helping Fabby!

Comment: @arshad: Thank you!  Improved even more!  **;-)**

Comment: will it work on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit?